# Python comprehensions. Assign vaule to matrix, looping through indexes

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

I would like to now if there is a way to do this in comprehensions.

I have a matrix (NxN) filled with zeros

```
control = np.zeros((7,7), dtype=np.int)
print control

array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I have a list of tuples giving me the indexes of this matrix in a spiral mode.

```
indx = [(3, 3), (4, 3), (4, 4), (3, 4), (2, 4), (2, 3), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (4, 5), (3, 5), (2, 5), (1, 5), (1, 4), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 6), (5, 6), (4, 6), (3, 6), (2, 6), (1, 6), (0, 6), (0, 5), (0, 4), (0, 3), (0, 2), (0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 0), (6, 0)]
```

My code is the following:

`for i in indx[0:7]:
    control[i] = 1`

I tried to use:

```
[control[i] = 1 for i in indx[0:7]]
```

But it gives me this error:

```
[control[i] = 1 for i in indx[0:7]]
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Expected result :

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Is there a way to do that in comprehensions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't have assignments in comprehensions.

Comment: Also `-16` is waaaay out of bounds for an array of your size. Please fix `indx` so the example can be reproduced. Also, expected output would be nice.

Comment: Technically, there are a few ways to do this, but it's generally considered bad practice to use a list comprehension merely for its side effects. In other words, if you aren't giving a name to the resulting list, you should probably just use a normal loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: comprehensions are designed to build new lists, using them for side effects is considered bad style, as it obfuscates the code and creates a useless throwaway container that needs to be garbage collected.

That being said, strictly answering your question if it is possible to do what you want to do with a comprehension, you could* but you should not do:

```
[control.__setitem__(i, 1) for i in indx[0:7]]
```

This will get you rightfully punched. What did you create that useless list for?

*If your original `for` loop did not throw an `IndexError` already, that is.

Comment: Thanks, then I'll do a normal loop, like @zondo and you said